# How to get average of specific teams and exclude negatives?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am given a text file and have to print out the average of the rows, the columns, and specific teams in the columns. I also have to exclude any negative values from the average.

Here is the text file

```
Tom, Red, 5, 17,22
Joe , Green , 3 , 14 ,22
Maria, Blue , 6 , 18 , 21
Fred , Blue , 2 ,15 ,23
Carlos , Red , -1 , 15, 24
```

Here is my row column average program

```
{s=$3+$4+$5; print $1 "\t" s/3} #Use awk program teamlist | sort -r -n to get the row average
```

Here is my column average program

```
{t+=$3}
{u+=$4}
{v+=$5}
 {print "Average for test 1: " t/NR}
 {print "Average for test 2: " u/NR}
 {print "Average for test 3: " v/NR} #Use awk column teamlist | tail -3 to the column average

Here are the results
Average for test 1: 4
Average for test 2: 13
Average for test 3: 20

Tom, 14.6668
Joe, 13
Maria, 15
```

I am not sure however how to modify the program to have awk only get the team colors and to skip the negative score.

Comment: you're deinitely on your way, but please edit your Q to show your required output from your sample input. Also include a description of where are you getting negative scores. Good luck.

Comment: I added output results.